# How to take an MSKLC-created layout into use in menus?

Tags: windows-10, installation, keyboard-layout, microsoft-klc

Having successfully created, installed, and distributed keyboard layout using MSKLC, I now noticed that even though I was able to create a new one and the installation process ends with an OK message, the layout isn’t available. The .dll file is at windows\system32 and the layout is in the list of installed programs, but I cannot find it via the language menu as a selectable layout. The problem is hardly in the layout name or description (I made them very simple, FICD, i.e. without spaces or any nonletters.)

This might be an unreproducible error, as it now seems that most of my layouts disappeared (some of them selected from those shipped with Windows 10, some created with MSKLC by me or others). But has anyone else encountered a problem like this? Besides, in Settings, Language, I can see some of the layouts that disappeared, either as being in use (which they aren’t) or as grayed out (whatever that means), but the newly created and installed one isn’t even there.

Comment: How and where are you installing this layout?

Comment: I simply used the setup created with MSKLC as before, clicking on the setup.exe icon, and I got a message saying that the installation was successful.

Comment: Check in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts` if your DLL is truly used for the layout.

Comment: I checked the registry key, and the DLL is there. My current guess is that the problem relates to the association of keyboards with languages, so that (for some odd reason) this keyboard is associated with no language.

Comment: Strange, but you could check the registry for your language, or try to repeat the installation.

Comment: Did you say that other keyboard layouts, including default ones, are disappearing? This sounds like system corruption. I am not familiar with the tool you mention. Have you checked for updates to this too? Reports of bugs similar to yours?